# Updating existing variable in Java

Tags: java

I've got the following code as an example(I've removed most of the code to make it easier)

Main class:

```
class TestStudent_3
{
    // To update student name to other name
    private void updateObject (Student s, String otherName)
    {
        s.setName (otherName);
    }

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
        ... All variables, methods and scanner inputs etc removed ...

        Student s = new Student (name, gender, age, subject1, subject2);
        s.displayStudentInfo ();

        // If you wish to change one the fields, you need to use mutator methods
        TestStudent_3 ts = new TestStudent_3 ();
        ts.updateObject (s, "New Name");
        s.displayStudentInfo ();
    }
}
```

Student class:

```
class Student
{
   private String name;

   ... All variables, methods and scanner inputs etc removed ...

   public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

---

My question is what's these few lines in the main method doing? And why can it update the existing record('s')

```
TestStudent_3 ts = new TestStudent_3 ();
```

What's this doing? Creating a new object ts?

```
ts.updateObject (s, "New Name");
```

Passing Student s object variables(contents) over to the updateObject method together with "New Name" string, why does this work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "why does this work" why shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm just curious as to why it works as I'm not how it's working. Why is a new object ts in the main class created and why does passing values of the previous object Student s and string of "New Name" allows the object Student s to be updated?

Answer (score 1):

Break it down.

```
s.setName(otherName);
```

sets the Name in instance `s` to otherName

```
ts.updateObject (s, "New Name");
```

is acting like a proxy of sorts.  It accepts an instance of `s` and the name and then
does the same thing in the `updateObject` method.

Comment: So it's actually "overwriting" the instance of s(in this case, the name variable) in the process? Not actually "searching and matching" instance s and replacing? ahhh it actually makes sense to overwrite, was confused as to how the statements are actually able to "search and match" the instance s earlier and replace the new variable only

Comment: It is overwritting `s's` name field, not the `instance of s`.  It is just using `s` to make the change.  No change is made to `ts` at all when `updateObject` is called. But it appears you do understand now.

Comment: So ts.updateObject (s, "New Name"); passes the instance s over to updateObject method so it can be used as s.setName to set the name right? ahh I see

Comment: What about the private void updateObject (**Student s**, String otherName)?
Why does does it have to be Student s? Is it like telling the method, hey we have a instance 's' coming through?

Comment: @Michelle C `s` is just the variable name to be used inside the method, it doesn't need to match the name you pass it from `main`.  `Student` is to signify that the method should expect a `Student` object in the first parameter when being called from somewhere (in this case the `main`).

Comment: @Nexevis I tried changing to private static void updateObject (Student **y**, String otherName), **y**.setName (otherName) and it still works, can you help me understand why? When updateObject (*s*, "New Name") happens, the instance **'s' identifier or something** is sent over and somehow the updateObject receiving it and then later calling the Student class knows I'm trying to update the 's' object/instance and not any other (like if I have Student z = new Student (name, gender, age, subject1, subject2) too) so it it correct to say updateObject (s, "New Name") passes a unique identifier of s

Comment: As was stated, it does not have to be `s`.  It can be any variable but it has to be in instance of Student.  And that means any instance.  If you had an array of 20 students and their names you could iterate over them and pass the student instance and the name to that method to change all the names.

Comment: Let's say I have 3 Student Instances a b c, updateObject (**b**, "New Name") passes through method but updateObject (Student **Y**) and then do a **Y**.setname, Instance **b still passes through**. As long as I **specify correctly which instance of Student I want to update in updateObject (b, "New Name")** earlier right?
I finally get it! Thanks alot for all your time and help!

Answer (score 1):

You pass an **object reference** to object `s` into the updateObject method.

So the updateObject method call:

```
<reference to s>.setName(otherName)
```

or you can say:

```
s.setName(otherName)
```

That will change the name value of the Student `s` object.

In the next line in the main method you call:

```
s.displayStudentInfo();
```

Thats kind of equal to:

```
<reference to s>.displayStudentInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are confused why the `ts` object had to be created with `TestStudent_3 ts = new TestStudent_3 ();` in order to update the `Student s`.

`updateObject` is not `static`, and is part of the `TestStudent_3` class, so in order to call that method, you need to have an object of the class and invoke it using the object, as you see with the `ts.updateObject(s, "New Name")` where `ts` is the object created just so you can use the method.

Realistically `updateObject` should be `static` the way it is written:

`private static void updateObject (Student s, String otherName)`

Because the `ts` object is not used at all for logic of the method, it is completely unnecessary.  If it was `static`, then you would just be able to use `updateObject(s, "New Name")` instead without the `ts.` (although you might as well just call `s.setName("New Name")` directly).